# Does "whenever a creature attacks" count for each attacker separately?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Hissing Miasma](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHissing%20Miasma%5d) is an enchantment that says:

> Whenever a creature attacks you, its controller loses 1 life.

Does the attacker lose one life per attacking creature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes (though they will be lost one at a time).

---

There's a rule specifically covering this:

> 603.2c An ability triggers only once each time its trigger event occurs. However, it can trigger repeatedly if one event contains multiple occurrences. See also rule 509.4.

If your opponent attacks you with an Elf and a Bear, two instances of the event "a creature attacks you" occurred (the Elf attacked you, and the Bear attacked you), so the ability will trigger twice.

You will place these on the stack where they will resolve one at a time, each causing him to lose one life (for a total of two).

Comment: _(though they will be lost one at a time)_
Huh. So, if that opponent has something that works like _"the next time a source will make you lose life, this prevents 2 life points of damage"_ that card should cancel ONLY the first point?

Comment: @juanzack, yup! The effect of the first ability to resolve is "its controller loses 1 life." This will be prevented. Then a second instance of the ability resolves. This is explained later in the post.

Comment: @juanzack, Except Hissing Miasma causes loss of life, not damage, so a damage prevention effect wouldn't do anything anyway.

Comment: ug, he used "lose life" in the trigger, but "damage" in the effect. He meant "The next time you would lose life, reduce the life lost by two." or something like that.

Comment: Haha yeah sorry, thanks ikegami, that's what I meant. This is interesting, since a card that would prevent the losing of 1 life from every source would completely negate Hissing Miasma.

Comment: True, but I don't know if there's anything that prevents life lost.

Comment: Well there's Platinum Emperion... but that would stop all the life loss, not just the first.

Comment: The number of triggers can matter, too. Consider Exquisite Blood and Archangel of Thune. If your opponent attacks with 4 creatures, you get 4 +1/+1 counters since you gained 1 life 4 times. If your opponent lost 4 life for the attackers all in one shot, you'd gain 4 life 1 time, which would mean you'd only get 1 +1/+1 counter. Swinging into some 1/1's that just turned into 5/5's would be devastating! :-O

Comment: Woah. That is certainly something that I will be testing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the attacker will lose one life per attacking creature.

The ability is a triggered ability, because it uses the word "whenever". The trigger is a creature having attacked, and if 5 creatures attack, then this will trigger 5 times.

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as "[Trigger condition], [effect]," and begin with the word "when," "whenever," or "at." They can also be expressed as "[When/Whenever/At] [trigger event], [effect]."

Comment: Great, that's what I thought! Thanks, I had to ask this anyway since the wording in Spanish is confusing.

Comment: @juanzack, Hm? The wording in Spanish is the same. "Siempre que una criatura te ataque, su controlador pierde 1 vida."

Comment: Tuve discusiones con amigos por "Siempre que una criatura te ataque", porque interpretaban eso como que se activaba UNA vez cuando en una fase de ataque enemiga 1 criatura o más atacaban.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the attacker will lose one life per attacking creature.

The ability is a triggered ability,when a ability is triggered it gets a 2nd trigger if say a elf and another creature attacks you as well

Comment: Please read existing answers, especially those with high scores, to see if an answer similar to yours had already been posted. If you post the same information that was posted three years ago, then your post may get a lower score. Of course, if you are confident that you can present the same information more clearly and understandably, then you should. I suggest sorting your questions page by ["newest to oldest"](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) instead of "most recently active", so that you can focus your efforts on newer questions.